# Node App not Running in the proper port with npm start. Shows random port

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, npm

I want to deploy this node app and while `npm start` and the app started successfully, though I changed the default node port from `3000` to `3003`, I was able to access the app from my `localhost:port` and then but it only displays the random port and file paths as shown below.

The error message
`{"message":" - Not Found - /","stack":"Error:  - Not Found - /\n    at notFound (/home/dareomotosho/main/middlewares/notFound.js:3:17)\n    at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (/home/dareomotosho/main/node_modules/express/lib/router/layer.js:95:5)\n    at trim_prefix (/home/dareomotosho/main/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:317:13)\n    at /home/dareomotosho/main/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:284:7\n    at Function.process_params (/home/dareomotosho/main/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:335:12)\n    at next (/home/dareomotosho/main/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:275:10)\n    at jsonParser (/home/dareomotosho/main/node_modules/body-parser/lib/types/json.js:110:7)\n    at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (/home/dareomotosho/main/node_modules/express/lib/router/layer.js:95:5)\n    at trim_prefix (/home/dareomotosho/main/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:317:13)\n    at /home/dareomotosho/main/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:284:7"}`

I am confused and don't know what else to do. Thank you for your kind response.

Comment: Perhaps your code has an error in it

Comment: @Jaromanda, which of the code you mean?